# Angular - How to prevent ngIf from destroying the component every time the condition changes

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-ng-if

I have this code :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let language of languages">
      <app-fields-to-translate
        *ngIf="language.ID === selectedLanguage.ID"
        [AttributeGroupsCollapses]="AttributeGroupsCollapses"
        [AttributeGroups]="AttributeGroups"
        [Attributes]="Attributes"
        [categoriesCollapsed]="categoriesCollapsed"
        [generalCollabsed]="generalCollabsed"
        [selectedLanguage]="selectedLanguage"
        (CategoriesCollapsedEmmiter)="categoriesCollapsed = $event"
        (CollapseGeneralEmmiter)="generalCollabsed = $event"
        (AddFieldToTranslation)="AddFieldToTranslation($event)"
        (AddAttrubuteToTranslation)="AddAttributeToTranslation($event)"
      >
      </app-fields-to-translate>
    </ng-container>
```

and every time the selctedLanguage changes the component of (field-to-translate) being destroyed
Can I prevent this process?
or is there another way to do this stuff?

Comment: Depending on what your business logic does exaclty, you could use `[hidden]`, ie `[hidden]="language.ID !== selectedLanguage.ID"`

Comment: my logic is displaying the component where the language has the same Id with the selected language ,please add you comment as answer to mark it as solution for m problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your business logic does exactly, you could use `[hidden]`, ie

`[hidden]="language.ID !== selectedLanguage.ID"`